Regular expression for a language that has equal number of ‘01’ and ‘10 substrings?
My understanding so far:
At first glance, it seemed like I had to keep track of all occurrences of ‘10’ and ‘01’ but that is not the case. At any given point, there are only three possibilities. Either the # of both substrings is equal, or # of ‘01’ is exactly one more than ‘10’ and vice versa. Consider this, lets say we start with 0, then we can have as many 0s after the initial 0 as we want, that doesn’t change anything. As soon as we get a 1, the number of ‘01’ becomes one more than ‘10’. Then again we can have as many 1s after the first 1, the situation remains the same. Then as soon as we get a 0, the number becomes equal again. Same is the case for if we begin with a 1.
Also it should accept empty string, string with a sequence of just 0s and string with a sequence of just 1s.
My attempt:
Based on my understanding, I came up with the following regex
(00* 11* 00*)* U (11* 00* 11*)*
Where left side of the union takes care of any strings that have the sequence 010 and right side takes care of any strings with the sequence 101.
Issue with my attempt:
It doesn’t accept strings with a sequence of just 0s and strings with a sequence of just 1s.
Potential fix:
We can change regex to
(00* 11* 00*)* U (11* 00* 11*)* U 0* U 1*
And that will accept strings with a sequence of just 0s and strings with a sequence of just 1s.
Issue with potential fix:
The above regex will accept ‘01’
Kindly help me with the solution to this problem. Feel free to correct any mistakes in my approach.

This is just the language of all strings that start and end in the same symbol, so a regular expression would be $\varepsilon \cup \Sigma \cup 0 \Sigma^* 0 \cup 1 \Sigma^* 1$.
Let's call any point where you switch from 0 to 1 an "up", and any point where you switch from 1 to 0 a "down". For example, "001110" has one up from the 2nd to the 3rd symbol followed by one down from the 5th to the 6th symbol. Then a string must alternate between ups and downs, where the first switch must be an up if the string starts with 0 and down if 1, and the last switch must be a down if the string ends with 0 and up if 1. So a string has an equal number of "01" and "10" substrings (i.e., equal number of ups and downs) iff it starts and ends with the same symbol: 0 gives up/down/.../up/down and 1 gives down/up/.../down/up.

These are just the strings which start with 0 and end with 0 or start with 1 and end with 1. Based on this the regular expression becomes, $R = \varepsilon \cup (0 \Sigma^* 0) \cup (1 \Sigma^* 1) \cup \Sigma$.
